# Cannot test the social framework on a device lower than IOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, frameworks

I am working with the social framework. On iPads with IOS6 it works fine. 
But when I test it on a device with IOS 5 I get the following error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3A3020E0-09D7-49DD-96E2-2E0F20C098D2/RacingGenk.app/RacingGenk
  Reason: image not found
```

Can anybody help ?

Kind regards.

Stef

Comment: Drumroll please.....Social.framework is an iOS 6 feature...what makes you think you can use it on iOS 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The social framework isn't available before iOS 6, which explains the problems you're having.

What you need to do is *weak link* the social framework, which will let you use it on iOS 6 but won't cause pre iOS 6 devices to try to load it. To weak link a library you should select your application's target in XCode, go to the *Build Phases* tab, and under *Link Binary with Libraries* make sure that the 'Social.framework' entry is set to *Optional* rather than *Required*.

Answer (score 1):

The social framework was introduced in iOS 6, but if you want you have sharing ability for facebook, twitter and many other social networks / sites on devices running versions of iOS before 6.0 then feel free to explore sharekit:

http://getsharekit.com/

Its really easy to use and works for both iOS 6 apps and apps running on previous versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the Facebook integration is only available on iOS6. You can however still use facebook using the original Facebook API for < IOS6 devices.